# Pandas - Concat different column levels MultiIndex DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Imagine we have a DataFrame created like this:

```
tmp_df = pd.DataFrame(index=xrange(10), columns=['3-1','3-2'])
tmp_df = pd.concat({'2-1': tmp_df, '2-2': tmp_df},axis=1)
tmp_df = pd.concat({'1-1': tmp_df, '1-2': tmp_df}, axis=1)
```

Which gives:

```
   1-1                 1-2               
   2-1       2-2       2-1       2-2     
   3-1  3-2  3-1  3-2  3-1  3-2  3-1  3-2
0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
3  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
4  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
5  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
6  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
7  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
8  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
9  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Thus, we have a three-level column indexed DataFrame. Nonetheless, if we want to concatenate to this a different two-level column indexed DataFrame such as:

```
tmp2_df = pd.Series(np.nan,index=xrange(10))
tmp2_df = pd.concat({'1-3':pd.concat({'2-1': tmp2_df, '2-2': tmp2_df},axis=1)},axis=1)

  1-3    
  2-1 2-2
0 NaN NaN
1 NaN NaN
2 NaN NaN
3 NaN NaN
4 NaN NaN
5 NaN NaN
6 NaN NaN
7 NaN NaN
8 NaN NaN
9 NaN NaN
```

Using `pd.concat(...)` destroys the hierarchy:

```
pd.concat([tmp_df,tmp2_df],axis=1).columns

Index([(u'1-1', u'2-1', u'3-1'), (u'1-1', u'2-1', u'3-2'),
       (u'1-1', u'2-2', u'3-1'), (u'1-1', u'2-2', u'3-2'),
       (u'1-2', u'2-1', u'3-1'), (u'1-2', u'2-1', u'3-2'),
       (u'1-2', u'2-2', u'3-1'), (u'1-2', u'2-2', u'3-2'),
               (u'1-3', u'2-1'),         (u'1-3', u'2-2')],
      dtype='object')
```

How can we mantain the column index hierarchy in a way that for `tmp2_df` there is not a 3rd level of column index? Output should be something like:

```
   1-1                 1-2                 1-3
   2-1       2-2       2-1       2-2       2-1  2-2
   3-1  3-2  3-1  3-2  3-1  3-2  3-1  3-2  
0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
3  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
4  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
5  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
6  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
7  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
8  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
9  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

I am aware that you can do things like:

```
tmp_df['test'] = pd.Series(np.nan,index=xrange(10))

   1-1                 1-2                test
   2-1       2-2       2-1       2-2          
   3-1  3-2  3-1  3-2  3-1  3-2  3-1  3-2     
0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
3  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
4  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
5  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
6  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
7  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
8  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
9  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

But this solution does not work for appending DataFrames:

```
ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're going to have to eat it and assign a third level to the new columns. Not sure having a hierarchical index with different levels based on the numerical position if each coming makes much sense. Not to mention that it would probably be incredibly cumbersome to maintain consistently.

Comment: @PMende that was my fear. This exercise is more academic than for a 'real use'. Nonetheless, I was thinking using a hierarchy like this for parsing a file, which contains statistics for the execustion of different cores. Each core has the parameter 'cycles', but also has a L1 which can be data or instruction, which also has hits and misses; I think you see where I am going. Said this, probably homogenizing all levels would be less painful, as you suggest.